# Textbox events?

Tags: selenium, webautomation, kantu

I am using Kantu to automate filling out some forms. There is a textbox that when a persons id number is entered and you click into another box or tab out of the textbox it will load that persons vcard. I can try to expound if you need more clarity.

I don't know much but i'm guessing me clicking into another box is activiating some kind of event to load this vcard. I can't seem to simulate this. Does anyone know of a way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Sample of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lk9H0.png)

I consulted with a friend who showed me the problem was an onblur event triggered by clicking away.

The solution to my problem was to call the event using the following line,

```
{
  "Command": "storeEval",
  "Target": "lawformTextBlur(document.getElementById('_f4'))",
  "Value": ""
},
```

Comment: I fixed your formatting but wasn't sure if I should have kept the final `,` after the closing `}`.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SO. There are different option to get the associated events.

Let's take the stackoverflow search box (the one which is on the top with `s-input js-search-field` class)

**1) Using getEventListeners**

Go to chrome console in the dev tools and then use `getEventListeners(element)`.

> getEventListeners(document.querySelector('.s-input.js-search-field '))

[image]

**2) Using Dev Tools Event Listner**

Go to chrome dev tools and select the element for which you want to know the events, click on the `Event Listeners` tab on the right hand side pane.
   [image]

**3) Using the firefox event**

Goto dev tools in firefox and click on `events` bubble at the end of html element tag. 
    [image]