# Clicking in an element in an iframe - Selenium Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, iframe

I have an `iframe` embedded into my webpage, and I'm using Selenium to automate tests:

```
<iframe class="wysihtml5-sandbox" security="restricted" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" width="0" height="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="display: block; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-collapse: separate; border-color: rgb(163, 192, 216); border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; clear: none; float: none; margin: 0px; outline: rgb(0, 0, 0) none 0px; outline-offset: 0px; padding: 6px 12px; position: static; top: auto; left: auto; right: auto; bottom: auto; z-index: auto; vertical-align: baseline; text-align: start; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.043) 0px 0.595067px 0.595067px 0px inset; border-radius: 4px; width: 100%; height: 434px;"></iframe>
```

Inside the `iframe` there's a body:

```
<body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" contenteditable="true" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-empty wysihtml5-editor placeholder" spellcheck="true" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: black; cursor: text; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: 400; line-height: 17.1429px; letter-spacing: normal; text-align: start; text-decoration: none solid rgb(0, 0, 0); text-indent: 0px; text-rendering: auto; word-break: normal; overflow-wrap: break-word; word-spacing: 0px;">Enter text ...</body>
```

I wrote the following Selenium automation to input text into that body, which actually displays as a text box:

```
iframes = wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CLASS_NAME, "wysihtml5-sandbox")))
if iframes:
    try:
        body = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("body")
        for b in body:
            b.clear()
            b.send_keys(text)
        time.sleep(2)
        # switch back to the original content
        browser.switch_to.default_content()
    except Exception as e:
       print(e)
```

The issue is whenever I enter a text ("foobar") and save, the text is not saved. I noticed if I click in the input box which the body represents, then the `text` is saved, otherwise it won't happen. I guess whomever wrote the code for this page expected the user to click and type in the input box (`body`) in order to save when the `iframe` is closed.
How can I emulate the same effect of clicking in the `iframe` input box in order to fix this bug in my automation?

Comment: Do you see an exception?

Comment: @DebanjanB there are no exceptions...

Comment: I have published an answer. Check it out and let me know the status.

Comment: @DebanjanB your solution didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the below options.

**option 1:**
click on the body element before entering the text/cleaning the text.

```
b.click()
# use javascript click(), if normal click not worked
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()",b)
```

**option 2:**
Trigger the on-change or associated event, after entering the data in the body.

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('onchange', {'bubbles': true,'cancelable': true}));",b)
```

You can try using the both options individually or combined.

Refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55977388/textbox-events/55978587#55978587) to know the events associated to the body element.

Answer (score 0):

### frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it()

[frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it()](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it) expectation for checking whether the given frame is available to switch to. If the frame is available it switches the given driver to the specified frame. This method doesn't returns anything. So irrespective of success/failure status of the execution of the following line of code :

```
iframes = wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CLASS_NAME, "wysihtml5-sandbox")))
```

`iframes` will be always **NULL** and the code block within `if iframes:` won't be executed.

Possibly your manual intervention is helping the driver to get the **focus** within the desired element and hence types the *text*. You need to make a small change and your effective code block will be:

```
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CLASS_NAME, "wysihtml5-sandbox")))
try:
    body = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("body")
    for b in body:
        b.clear()
        b.send_keys(text)
    time.sleep(2)
    # switch back to the original content
    browser.switch_to.default_content()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```