# After the text is entered in the input , the search icon is not clickable

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

My problem is that I am not being able to click on the search icon after the text is being entered. Using the below code to enter the text and click on search icon.

Can you please let me know what mistake I am doing? Below is the code I am using

```js
.then(function() {
  log("Search Box");
  return $browser.waitForAndFindElement(By.css(inputs.searchBox), DefaultTimeout); })
  .then(function(el) {
    return $browser.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','Synthetics');",el)
  .then(function(){
     return $browser.findElement(By.css(inputs.searchBox)).click();
  })
})
.then(function(){
 $browser.waitForAndFindElement(By.xpath(inputs.searchBtn), DefaultTimeout)
 return $browser.findElement(By.xpath(inputs.searchBtn)).click()
})
```

Comment: Try sending the `onChange` or the corresponding event. You can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55977388/textbox-events/55978587#55978587) to know the associated event(s).

Comment: I tried to verify the event listeners for the element which i want to input the text. But i am seeing it invalid