# Python selenium whatsapp- search button

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, whatsapp, sendkeys

I am searching contacts through phone number and sending message in whatsapp using python selenium.
But i am not able to find the name, when I input in the search using send keys, it is getting deleted, when it goes to next element.
I want to know how to use alternate `driver.executescript` or where the attribute searched stays, and I can find the name of that .

```
 v_elem=driver.find_element_by_class_name('_3u328')
 v_elem.send_keys(phone))
 driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span[class="_19RFN _1ovWX _F7Vk"]').click()
```

When the script send keys, it deletes before finding the next css .. as that is where the name of the number exist.
How to find this.

Comment: Please post HTML section of that button

Comment: Find the associated event to the field and trigger the same using js. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55977388/textbox-events/55978587#55978587) post to know how to find the associated event.

Comment: [code]<div class="_3u328 copyable-text selectable-text" data-tab="3" dir="ltr" contenteditable="true"></div>[/code] this is html section i am trying to key in value for phone number.

Comment: i tried the following, instead of send key, but execute script is not setting the value for this element ,i want to search number&select name                                                                          javaScript = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='_3u328 copyable-text selectable-text']")
#driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value ='+phone+'",javaScript)

Comment: Hi supputuri, in that case, how to stop events.. i saw that 5 events associated to this particular one..Can you guide me, how to do. i saw d post, i could not entirely understand.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample script to trigger `onclick` event.

```
ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='_3u328 copyable-text selectable-text']") driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value =123",ele)
# now fire the even associated with the element here
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('click', {'bubbles': true,'cancelable': true}));",ele)
```

Comment: dirver.execute_script is not putting value in DOM, eventhough no error is thrown.i am using firefox as browser. Hence the value is not entered in the searchbox at all.

Comment: if i do               driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute.value('value','123');",ele)                 <div class="_3u328 copyable-text selectable-text" data-tab="3" dir="ltr" contenteditable="true", value="123"></div>

Comment: but the value is not updated , when i try driver.execute_script , above is the html code pasted.. i tried yours and also checked whether attribute changing. but attribute changes, not the value updates .. i am not knowing y?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I had to solve it using an inelegant procedure.

I used a mouse-bot to click on the search button, then I used a keyboard-bot to type the name I want to search for. You will have to adapt "x" and "y" for your screen.

This specific segment of the code are shown below.

```
import time
import win32api, win32con
import keyboard

x=179
y=287
win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)

time.sleep(1)
keyboard.write('Contact_name', delay=0.1)
```