# Entered values removed after clicks on another element in the web application

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, dom-events, sendkeys, cucumber-java

I'm having an input field where we need to enter some values, but then that input field will update with currency value, but when I automate this filled value set to empty once after click on another element. How do I figure this out?

I have attached the screenshot of my application:

[image: screenshot]

And below is my code I'm using:

```
jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('Amount1').setAttribute('value', '20')");
```

Even I tried using <kbd>TAB</kbd> key events, but still the same behaviour is there.

Comment: Are you using IE for execution? And why are  trying to set the value using js, normal `.send_keys` method should do the job, right?

Comment: @supputuri No i'm using Chrome. I used .sendkeys and it was not working then i used js but still it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i was able to find an answer for this issue.
One main reason was the element was stale once after entering the values so i had to re initialise them again.(but i don't think it's the best coding practice)

```
javascriptHelper.enterTextToField(amount2, driver.findElement(“id of the amount field”));


    javascriptHelper.clickOnElement(WebElementExtension.WaitForElementId(driver, "id of the amount field",
            driverWaitHelper.waitingTime()));

    WebElement textEleAmount2 = driver.findElement(By.id("id of the amount field"));
    textEleAmount2.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);


    javascriptHelper.clickOnElement(WebElementExtension.WaitForElementId(driver, "id of the name field",
            driverWaitHelper.waitingTime()));

    //Here I’m initialising the element again due to stale element reference
    WebElement amountContractor2 = WebElementExtension.WaitForElementId(driver, "id of the amount field",
            driverWaitHelper.waitingTime());

    // erase any existing value in the amount field
    for (int i = 0; i < amountContractor2.getAttribute("data-value").length(); i++) {
        amountContractor2.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE);
    }

    amountContractor2.sendKeys("300");

    javascriptHelper.jsTriggerEventOnElement(driver, amountContractor2, "change");

    // click away to fire on change event
    javascriptHelper.clickOnElement(driver.findElement(By.id("id of the name field")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try triggering the `onchange` or associated event using the below funciton.

```
public static void jsTriggerEventOnElement(WebDriver driver, WebElement element, String eventName) { 
        String jsFunction = " var genericEvent = document.createEvent ('Event');  clickEvent.initEvent ('" + eventName + "', true, true); arguments [0].dispatchEvent (genericEvent); ";
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript(jsFunction, element);
}
```

You can trigger the event by using the below line of code after entering the value in the field.

```
// enter the value using the normal send_keys/js

// now call the jsTriggerEventOnElement method, here we are triggering the onchange event 
// please change the event based the associated event
jsTriggerEventOnElement(driver, element, 'onchange`)
```

Please refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55977388/textbox-events/55978587#55978587) that will give an idea to find out the associated events. But, you can always try with `onchange` as a first check.

**Edit**

Try with the below.

```
public static void jsTriggerEventOnElement(WebDriver driver, WebElement element, String eventName) { 
        String jsFunction = " var clickEvent = document.createEvent ('Event');  clickEvent.initEvent ('" + eventName + "', true, true); arguments [0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent); ";
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript(jsFunction, element);
    }
jsTriggerEventOnElement(driver,element, 'onblur');
```

Comment: Even with "onchange" the value I entered disappeared.

Comment: Can you check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55977388/textbox-events/55978587#55978587) and find the associated event.

Comment: try with `blur`.

Comment: So instead on 'onchange' do u need to use 'blur'

Comment: Still its gives me empty field. I added the 'jsTriggerEventOnElement' just after the sendkeys.

Comment: hmm, Is it a publicly accessible website?

Comment: were you able to access the link i mentioned above. If then i'll remove that comment as it's our testing environment URL.

Comment: Please remove it

Comment: even i tried with element.sendKeys(Keys.TAB). Its not working, still update the input field to empty field.